# How to extend button size on hover event in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5

For example, there is some kind of docked application. It is pinned to the right border of the screen after launching. It contains only a list of buttons/icons. When user hovers on icon it should be extended, for example

[image: example]

At the end user can click on it and appropriate dialog should appear on the screen.

How do you think what Qt features I should use to do it?

Comment: You need to handle events of your button (sub class QPushButton) and resize it as soon as a hover event is triggered.

Comment: @vahancho yes, agreed and how about animation? Have you already work with animation during resizing?

Comment: to animate resizing you can use `QPropertyAnimation`, i.e. `QPropertyAnimation(myButton, "width");` etc.